# Email sending service

Tags: php, html-email, email

I want to send emails from my CMS using email service.

I have php array of email addresses and I would like to post the array with subject and message to email service and it would send emails to everyone.

Sometimes I will only send one email (user registration). Also a html newsletter should be possible.

So, which service to use? Any recommendations?

Comment: Why not use PHP `mail()`?

Comment: @mooseman: because PHP mail() is useless garbage if you want to have a reasonable chance of your mail NOT getting spammed. PHPMailer or Swiftmailer are far better for such things.

Comment: @MarcB It depends on the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) or [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). The [PHP mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function is an option as well.

Comment: I started to use postmarkapp.com